# Crash after change screen fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-orientation

I want to send data with a bundle and retrieve them in another fragment.

My problem is that the application crashes when I change the orientation of the screen in **Fragment Receive**.

Here is a piece of my code:

**Fragment Receive :**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_actuality, container, false);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    ImageView networkImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    textcontent = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.content);
    texttitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    textdate = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.date);
    textweb = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.web);



    textcontent.setText(Html.fromHtml(bundle.getString("article")));
    textdate.setText("le " + bundle.getString("date"));
    texttitle.setText(bundle.getString("title"));
    textweb.setText("Pour plus d'information : " + bundle.getString("urlweb")); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your activity in the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Answer (score 1):

***You should always check for null when using bundle***

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_actuality, container, false);
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    ImageView networkImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

        textcontent = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.content);
        texttitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textdate = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        textweb = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.web);


        if(savedInstanceState!=null){  
        textcontent.setText(Html.fromHtml(bundle.getString("article")));
        textdate.setText("le " + bundle.getString("date"));
        texttitle.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("title"));
        textweb.setText("Pour plus d'information : "savedInstanceState.getString("urlweb"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On rotation, your fragment is recreated, `onCreateView()` will be called again and getArguments will be null. So you need to save the data in `onSaveInstanceState()` and in `onCreateView()`, add if `savedInstanceState` is null, you get the data from `getArgument()` else you get the data from `savedInstanceState`.